# slashcommandbuilder Level card canvacord not working

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

Hey i try to make a /level command where you get a canvacord card where you see you level and other stuff. I dont see any mistake in the code to you see an error?

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const Levels = require("discord-xp");
const fs = require("fs");
const canvacord = require('canvacord');
const { MessageAttachment } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("level")
        .setDescription("see you level"),
    async execute(client, interaction) {

        try {
            const target = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author; // Grab the target.

            const user = await Levels.fetch(target.id, message.guild.id); // Selects the target from the database.

            const rank = new canvacord.Rank()
            .setAvatar(target.displayAvatarURL({format: 'png', size: 512}))
            .setCurrentXP(user.xp) // Current User Xp
            .setRequiredXP(Levels.xpFor(user.level + 1)) // We calculate the required Xp for the next level
            .setRank(user.position) // Position of the user on the leaderboard
            .setLevel(user.level) // Current Level of the user
            .setProgressBar("#FFFFFF")
            .setUsername(target.username)
            .setDiscriminator(target.discriminator);

            rank.build()
                .then(data => {
                const attachment = new MessageAttachment(data, "RankCard.png")
                interaction.reply({ files: [attachment] });
            })
            
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("hey")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the version of `discord.js` in your project

Comment: What do you mean by not working?